# What are possible ways to force download in browser on external url file?

Tags: javascript, download, http-headers, content-type

I extract direct URL to file on services like Youtube, Soundclound, Vimeo etc.

```js
https://ec-media.sndcdn.com/ZtPlxyZHyzxy.128.mp3?f10880d39085a94a0418a7ef69b03d522cd6dfee9399eeb9a522059e6dfebe3a874f334a009662382c4e7253eb6a082048cebfc69bee539b09d0559146b98e37f7b1637ebc
```

To download instead of opening in browser I currently use only download attribute that works only in Chrome and Firefox. I tried to set headers for 'Content-Disposition': 'attachment' to files, but those services obviously don't allow to post headers.

Is there anything else I could try to provide download?